# Looking for a block diagram from this schematic

Tags: diagram, schematic

I'm looking for the block diagram from this schematic. My concern is the multi-feedback. I don't really know how I could model it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQXvx0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You will need to provide values for the components shown, and then you can run a simulation to see how it performs. It may be possible to construct a mathematical formula with unspecified values, but that could be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Place a resistor \$R_{in}\$ between the plus and minus pins of the op-amp.

Use the real op-amp open loop gain (still an approximation):
$$G_{OL}=\frac{-A_{VOL}}{\tau s+1}$$

Recognize that a voltage difference can be represented with a summing junction and that the paths joining at the minus input of the op-amp is a current summing juntion as well

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzK6Dh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You probably expect clean blocks where the total effect of 2 cascaded blocks is got by multiplying the effect description (=transfer) functions of the blocks.

Unfortunately electric circuits rarely are so simple. You have differently behaving quantities - voltages and currents. In circuit theory you can for ex. write equations where the variables are node voltages. You write the equations based on Ohm's law, Kirchoff's laws and assuming the current of a capacitor is C(dV/dt). The opamp maybe can assumed to be ideal for simplicity and the box G generates its output voltage by multiplying the opamp output voltage with its transfer function. I guess its clear that you must operate in s-plane i.e. use the Laplace transforms of the currents and voltages. Or alternatively you write the state variable differential equations among some algebraic equations.

By writing a proper group of equations you write the law what happens in the circuit. Your every equation, of course, can be presented as interconnected blocks.That will be quite a complex block diagram. It presents the laws in the circuit and it will not at all resemble the schematic.

I'm afraid you wanted a simple rule how to convert the schematic to blocks to become able to write easily the law of the circuit. And I told just the opposite: Find the law of the circuit as a group of equations and preset it as blocks if someone has ordered you to draw the equivalent block diagram.

That's because there's no easy way to see the blocks at first. They can be drawn after the one has found the equations for the circuit, not before. A person who has done his homeworks well may build the equations directly as a block diagram drawing. Essentially this is writing the equations with a graphic image language. Module Simulink in Matlab is for them. There are also free block input capable system simulation programs. One of them is circuit analysis program Microcap which has numerous commonly needed ideal math blocks.

Often circuits are designed in a way that at a qualitative block diagram can be drawn easily, but that's useless for calculations, it only helps others to understand designer's main idea. Also quantitatively valid block diagram can be easy if the circuit is designed so that all blocks have their nominal loads which make the blocks to perform their nominal transfer functions. Your circuit is not such case.

The s-plane equation group can be simplified to Vout = (T)Vin where (T) is the s-plane transfer function. (T) can be factorized and especially trained eyes can see feedback loops. These make possible to present the circuit law as a purely imagined block diagram with very simple blocks, but that also doesn't present the physical circuit, it presents only its math law. And the derived law omits all internal quantities in the circuit, it's the relation between the input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a simple (rough) block diagram.
Both closed-loop gain values A1 and A2 are negative.

A1= - (Zr/R2)  and A2= -(Zr/R3)  with Zr=(R1+1/sC1)||(1/sC2)

[image]